# delete files after certain date with dropbox_uploader.sh

Tags: bash, ubuntu, dropbox

I'm running backup my DB using [dropbox_uploader.sh](https://github.com/andreafabrizi/Dropbox-Uploader). backupds are saved in dropbox by a naming convention based on date:

```
DATE=$(date +"%d-%m-%Y_%H%M") 
BKP_FILE="pal_BK_$DATE.sql"
```

. e.g `pal_BK_12-12-2016_1311.sql`.
 is there any way to delete backups older than one month from dropbox?

Comment: dropbox_uploader.sh has a function to list the contents of a folder and another one to remove an specific content. Have you tried to compute the current date, substract a month, list all the backups and erase those that are older? Do you need us to help you in that process or do you want to do it in a different way?

Comment: I'm thinking about a way to check creation date of backup files and then delete outdated backups. i dont know how to *erase those that are older*? is there any way to put listed dropbox folder backup files names in a variable(array) and then loop over that array to find outdated backups?

Comment: You should convert your current DATE to seconds. Then for each entry of the ./dropbox_uploader.sh list $DEST_DIR you convert the date present in the fileName to seconds and use a normal integer comparison. This process can be quite annoying using your current date format so, would you consider another date format to do this process with sort -kM ?

Comment: I can change time format if needed . please post your answer

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if it was useful.

Answer (score 3):

Without modifying the date format the comparison between files becomes a little bit weird but this is going to be fine.

The idea is to compute the current date (in your format) and the limit erase date (1 month before) in seconds. Then for each entry of the listed files, we retrieve the date, we convert it to seconds and we int-compare with the stated limit. If the file is enough old, we erase it.

```
#!/bin/bash 

#####################
# Convert a given date to s (leaves result in DATE_IN_S)
#####################
dateToS() {
  local date=$1

  local year=$(echo $date | tr "-" "\t" | tr "_" "\t" | awk {' print $1 '})
  local month=$(echo $date | tr "-" "\t" | tr "_" "\t"| awk {' print $2 '})
  local day=$(echo $date | tr "-" "\t" | tr "_" "\t" | awk {' print $3 '})
  local hour=$(echo $date | tr "-" "\t" | tr "_" "\t" | awk {' print $4 '} | cut -c -2)
  local minute=$(echo $date | tr "-" "\t" | tr "_" "\t" | awk {' print $4 '} | cut -c 3-)
  local seconds="00"

  # Compute the date time in s
  DATE_IN_S=$(date -d "${year}-${month}-${day} ${hour}:${minute}:${seconds}" +%s)
}


#####################
# MAIN CODE
#####################

DEST_DIR= # Dropbox backups base folder
DATE=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d_%H%M")
BKP_FILE="pal_BK_${DATE}.sql"

# Compute the limit date to erase files
LIMIT_DATE=$(date +%s)
LIMIT_DATE=$((LIMIT_DATE-2592000)) # 1 month in seconds

# Retrieve the list of files
files=$(./dropbox_uploader.sh list $DEST_DIR | awk {' print $3 '} | tail -n +2)

# Process each file
for file in $files; do
  fileDate=$(echo $file | tr "_" "\t" | tr "." "\t" | awk {' print $3"_"$4 '})        
  
  # Retrieve file date in seconds
  dateToS $fileDate

  # Erase the file if it exceeds the limit date
  #echo "[DEBUG] Comparing ${DATE_IN_S} - ${LIMIT_DATE}"
  if [ ${DATE_IN_S} -lt ${LIMIT_DATE} ]; then
     echo "[INFO] Erasing file $file"
     ./dropbox_uploader.sh delete ${DEST_DIR}${file}
  fi
done
```

Notice that:

- The function dateToS converts your specific date format to its equivalent in seconds
- To get the list of files we use dropbox_uploader.sh list and we awk the 3rd field (only filename) and we remove the first line (INFO line)
- I have added some echo messages for the sake of clarity but you can obviously remove them (the dropbox-uploader.sh calls can also be performed on silent mode).

Comment: In the dateToS function, day and year variable need to be interchanged (right now year variable is assigned the day part of the string and vice versa).

Comment: @sonam I am really surprised nobody find it out before. Thanks for the comment. I have already updated the answer with the correct solution.

Comment: thanks for the neat function - saved me time. This should have been accepted as the correct answer.